# Exclude a mailbox from "All Inboxes" or compose a custom multiple inbox view

Tags: email, iphone, exchange, mobile-mail

I have recently added my work mailbox to my iphone.

I have several other mailboxes that I use for non work purposes. I like to look at the mail from my non work mailboxes as though they were a single mailbox, so I use the "All Inboxes" option in the mail app.

I would like to exclude work emails from the "All Inboxes" view, is this possible? Failing that is there a way to create a view of my own that only includes my non work mailboxes?

I've had a look at [Exclude mails from specific Inbox in “Inbox” view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31694/exclude-mails-from-specific-inbox-in-inbox-view) but nothing there fits my situation, and that's for mail.app anyway.

I can't see any way to create a multi inbox entry, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: no you cannot. But if you want, you could download other mail apps like "Mailbox" or "Mail Pilot".

Answer (score 3):

This can now be done via the filter option in iOS Mail. Very handy. You just tap the filter button in the lower left, then tap the blue filter criteria in the center bottom, then adjust the options.